# SQL Server Extended event filters: can you use an IN predicate with a subquery?

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

I have an extended event that tracks and filters login events from specific users. The filter is something like this:

```
WHERE (([sqlserver].[nt_user]=N'fredJohnson') OR ([sqlserver].[nt_user]=N'sallySmith')))
```

What I would really like to do is use an IN, and have it filter off a much larger list of users. I have these usernames stored in a table. I want to go the subquery route because this EE will be pushed to many different databases with many different users. So for example, I would want it to do something like this, where the lname column is a list of a few hundred users from a table:

```
   WHERE (([sqlserver].[nt_user]=N'Select lname from @Tbl')))
```

But it doesn't works. Any ideas how to pull this off?

The full EE i'm trying to modify:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [TrackLogins] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.login(
    ACTION(package0.collect_system_time,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.server_instance_name,sqlserver.session_nt_username,sqlserver.username)
    WHERE (([sqlserver].[nt_user]=N'Select lname from @Tbl')))

WITH (STARTUP_STATE=ON)
GO
```

Comment: Have you tried `[nt_user] IN (Select lname from @Tbl)?

Comment: I did and unfortunately it doesn't like IN as part of the syntax, even if I tried to do only two hardcoded options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Extended Event filters can't run queries.  Extended event filters need to be very cheap, so you should favor over-collecting events to over-filtering them.

Comment: appreciate it, any thoughts then on filtering from an NT_Group instead of an NT_User? My main goal is to track when a member of an NT_group logs into to a database. I was trying to use a table populated by xp_logininfo data to do this, because I don't see an nt_group option.

Comment: If the user has access through a group the logon event still shows the user's individual identity, not the group.

Comment: That is ok for my purposes, but I am hoping to collect only the logins from that group. I only need to filter behind the scenes. For example, to filter from an AD group called 'Domain\DB_Group', even if the events only show that individual user login when recorded. This way, only login events relevant to me will show up in my event_file

Comment: Collect them all and filter them later.  Logon is not a high-velocity event.

Comment: Wouldn't the filtering be the same though, where on the event_file, I can only filter where nt_username = 'specificname', rather than filtering members of an AD group, because that field isn't being captured? It is confusing because if I can filter logins to a specific database, it should be the same impact as filtering members of an AD group

Comment: You can join and filter when reading the extend event file.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-xe-file-target-read-file-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: ty looks like that is my only option